# Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'L'

Tags: android, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this error in my logcat when imported appcompat v7 from " sdk/extras/android/ "

> Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set
>   minSdkVersion to 'L'

[image]

and the manifest is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="android.support.v7.appcompat">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application />
</manifest>
```

how can i resolve this error?

> or how can i import it with android 4.2.2 in the package
>   explorer,which now it is showing andoid L(Preview)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In projects Properties -> Android You have to choose other than Android-L, 
In example Android 4.4W, because they have the same API number - API-20
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Set this

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L"/>
```

Comment: it is  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/> in manifest and it is a library that i imported

Comment: @mapo But what if it's not the range of supported APIs that you'd wish to have?

Comment: And for Android M set it to MNC

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

to

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L"/>
```

Comment: And for Android M set it to MNC