# Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'L' when importing library

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am adding this library - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility

When I add the `library` folder to the project explorer (import into), I get the error:

> Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set
>   minSdkVersion to 'L'

I have changed the `android:mindSdkVersion` from 9 (which it came as) to L and it has not worked. I changed it in the Project Build Target within properties also, to no avail.

Comment: I don't know if it applies, but have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507717/platform-l-is-a-preview-and-requires-application-manifest-to-set-minsdkversion-t

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have chosen to build your app using android L
to change it  select adifferent version for the build.
choose Project -> Properties -> android-> (any version lower than L)