# Platform MNC is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'MNC'

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have this error in my console.

[2015-06-03 15:29:11 - MainActivity] Platform MNC is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'MNC'
[2015-06-03 15:29:12 - debug] Platform MNC is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'MNC'

and the manifest is like

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

how can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 4):

IF you are trying to implement any project for Android M developer preview, You need to set minSDKVERSION ="MNC".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the new api in `Android M(preview)`, you have to do that.

But if you don't need, change your build target to other version.

In Eclipse, `Properties` -> `Android`, select target other than `Android M (Preview)`

Comment: I have changed the build target to Android 5.1.1, but now the androidmanifest.xml is showing error (android:icon="@drawable/icon" -  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon'))

Comment: @SantoshShetty make sure the icon.png resource is existing.

Comment: yaa i did that and the error is gone, but when i say build project nothing happens. i'm using Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: @SantoshShetty What did you mean, nothing happened? the build processing not started or your apk doesn't be generated?

Comment: the build processing not started

Comment: @SantoshShetty can't figure out what happened, any error log message?

Answer (score 0):

Platform MNC is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'MNC'so you should try SDK INT OF MNC

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

In projects Properties -> Android You have to choose other than Android-M, In above example Android 5.1.1, because they have the same API number - API-22

refer this:
[Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'L'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507717/platform-l-is-a-preview-and-requires-application-manifest-to-set-minsdkversion-t?rq=1)

Comment: Except that API 22 is Lollipop MR1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already resolved this issue or not, but all you need to do is this:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="MNC"
android:targetSdkVersion="MNC" />
```